# .Net 4.0 Routing using Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, routes

I'm trying to convert a site from classic asp to .Net 4.0 using URL Routing. I've set up IIS6 to wildcard map all incoming requests through the .Net .dll. So far everything seems to be working great. The old URL structure is extremely uniform so writing the `MapPageRoutes` has been a breeze. So much so, I'm concerned at how easy this task is shaping up to be. I'm new to url routing so I'd just like to know if there are any gotchas or something I need to watch out for here?

Answer (score 1):

If you've gotten this far and don't have any issues then give yourself a pat on the back.  Just judging from your description the only thing I can think of that could be an issue would be the IIS6 wildcard mapping.  It can turn into a performance issue if you have a cpu intensive website, so be careful there.  .Net 4.0 routing is also supposed to just work right out of the box with IIS6.  So if your wildcard becomes an issue you may want to look into [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx).